# React UI doesn't get updated, why?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, called Bucket, each bucket can have multiple challenges, it looks like this,
[image]

The code I have is like this, (much-simplified version)

```
class CLL_Bucket extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {};
      this.state = {
         …
         bucketChallengesIdx: 0,       // to track the index of challegnes  
         bucketChallenges: this.props.bucket.bucketChallenges || [],
         …
      };

      …
    this.onBucketChallengeAdd = this.onBucketChallengeAdd.bind(this);
      this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged = this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged.bind(this);
      this.onBucketChallengeWeightChanged = this.onBucketChallengeWeightChanged.bind(this);
   }

render() {
   const bucketIdx = this.props.idx;

   return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
         <div key={bucketIdx} className="row" style={styles.bucketStyle}>
            <div className="col-md-2">
               …
            </div>
            <div key={bucketIdx} className="col-md-4">
               <div>
                  <label>
                     <span className="text-center">Challenges<span>
                  </label>
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={() => this.onBucketChallengeAdd()}>Add Challenge</button>
               </div>
               <table className="table table-bordered table-striped show">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Challenge ID</th>
                     <th>Weight</th>
                     <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  {this.state.bucketChallenges.map(this.renderBucketChallenges.bind(this))}
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            …
         </div>
      </div>
   );
}

renderBucketChallenges(bucketIdx, idx){
   return (
      <tr key={idx}>
         <td className="col-xs-3 input-group-sm">
            <Select
               options={challengeIDOptions}
               defaultValue={challengeIDOptions[0]}
               onChange={this.onBucketChallengeIDChanged.bind(this, idx)}
               value={this.state.bucketChallengesID}
               isSearchable={true}
            />
         </td>
         <td className="col-xs-1 input-group-sm">
            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.bucketChallengesWeight}
                  onChange={(e) => this.onBucketChallengeWeightChanged(idx, e)} disabled={this.props.readOnly}>
            </input>
         </td>
         <td className="col-xs-1 input-group-sm">
            …
         </td>
         <td className="col-xs-1 input-group-sm">
            <input className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="deleteButton" type="button" value="Delete" onClick={() => this.onDeleteChallenge.bind(this, bucketIdx, idx)} />
         </td>
      </tr>
   );
}

onBucketChallengeAdd(){
   var newChallengeIndex = this.state.bucketChallengesIdx + 1;
   console.log("onBucketChallengeAdd(): " + newChallengeIndex);
   this.setState({bucketChallengesIdx: newChallengeIndex});
   this.props.onAddChallenge(this.props.idx, newChallengeIndex);
}
```

The problem I’m having is, when I click the “Add Challenge” button, I can see from the React developer tool that a new challenge is being added, even though the UI is not updated. When I go to a different tab of my app and come back, the UI is added (a new row for the added challenge is there). Why? Any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks!

The bigger question is, am I on the right track to make this happen? or i should extract challenge portion to a different component?